# Logical indexing - numpy.where in C++

Tags: python, c++, numpy, eigen

I have created a simple numpy array with shape (4, 2) called `A`.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1, 2], 
              [2, 2],  
              [3, 2], 
              [4, 2]])
```

I wanted to get the index of the rows where the first column is 2 and 3, so I did:

```
indices = np.where((A[:, 0] == 2) | (A[:, 0] == 3))[0]
```

Doing this I got an array with two items (1 and 2), which is what I wanted.

Now I would like to do this in C++ efficiently. Is there any way to do this using Eigen? I would like to avoid for loops.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoiding `for` loops in NumPy is admirable.  But in fact all you're doing there is pushing the loops down into lower-level code implemented in C or Fortran.

There is simply no need to avoid loops in C++.  On the contrary, loops are the clear and obvious way to solve this problem in C++.  So use loops.  They're blazing fast.

Answer (score 1):

this is numpy in c++ it is using for loop to do [where]

https://github.com/dpilger26/NumCpp/blob/master/include/NumCpp/Functions/where.hpp

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31660493)